# What's the right way to call Dialogs in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have followed Google Documentation regarding Dialogs and I have tried to implement it.

When I run my script I got an error that 'Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context or 'Cannot read property undefined of alert'.

My implementation is really basic:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('SUB')
    .addItem('A')
    .addItem('B')
    .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Do you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Done');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Aborted');
    return;
  }
}
```

My function call:

```
let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.alert('There were some erros in the process');
ui.showAlert;
```

I believe my implementation is not right as the documentation shows it as custom buttons. How do I call it inside my main function?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not a method of Class UI.

Try running it as shown in test:

```
function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert('Please confirm','Do you want to continue?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Done');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Aborted');
    return;
  }
}

function test() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('There were some erros in the process');
  showAlert();//The difference is here
}
```

It runs just fine this way.

Comment: I hope that helps.  You nearly had it all except for adding the ui